# Keep track of API data in React

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, state

I am trying to find a solution for making two API calls and retrieve the data I need.

For last param *editedBy* I am getting a long id as a string, so I was asked to make a second API call where I can find the corresponded *id* for my param.
I will need to take in consideration the fact that even if now the app holds a user, in time the number will increase so I need to keep track of every person’s data and who made the edit. My question is how do I do that?

For now, I tried the below code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { getManagerUser } from '/api.js';
import { getUser } from './api.js';

const DisplayDataComponent = () => {
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('');
    const [editedBy, setEditedBy] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
    getManagerUser(managerId).then(res => {
        const managerData = res.data

        getUser(userId).then(res => {
            const userData = res.data

            setFirstName(managerData);
            setLastName(managerData);
            setEditedBy(`${userData.firstName} ${userData.lastName}`);
        })
    })
},[])

return (
    <div>
        <p>{firstName}</p>
        <p>{lastName}</p>
        <p>{editedBy}</p>
    </div>
)}
```

And for better understanding I hardcoded the API info:

```
const manager = [
    {
        id: "2jdd00934hflsp443esd",
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Smith',
        editedBy: '3hdifu03434kdlfjvds'
    }
]

const user = [
    {
        id: '3hdifu03434kdlfjvds',
        firstName: 'Marry',
        lastName: "James"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is that the scenario should be handled by backend. Backend should support one API to provide the complete data.